# Regular expression to match any combination of repeated values

Tags: php, regex

I need to test strings for repeated chars. Is there an singular regular expression I could use for this or should I compile a list of multiple different regular expressions?

```
111333555777
aaaabbbbccccdddd
aabbcc
11111
abcabcabc
```

There's a couple of different types of repetition

Comment: post expected o/p

Comment: what is your effort so far..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get you right, but maybe this regex would be what you want

```
^(?:(.*)\1+)*$
```

matches

```
111333555777
aaaabbbbccccdddd
aabbcc
11111
abcabcabc
```

Answer (score 1):

By use of a [capturing groups and backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) check, if string consists only by repeated values.

```
^(?:(\w+)\1+)+$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wOwIJn/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is like the others, except the inner capture expression is non-greedy.
Not really sure if it maters though it insures the finest granularity.

`(?:(.+?)\1+)+`

It is probably impossible though to get the repeating boundary's via capture
group info.